# Ensure vars.get in a JSR223 postprocessor will set value only in current thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, performance-testing

In JMeter, I have a Thread Group which has a child JSR223 sampler.
This JSR223 sampler attempts to execute some code to get a message from a remote system and if it is successful, it sets a variable var1 like so:

```
vars.put('var1', var1)
```

Then, in a child JSR223 PostProcessor of this JSR223 sampler, I do:

```
var1 = vars.get('var1')
```

Then I use var1 for some calculations to amend the parent JSR223 sampler results.

I am concerned that if I spawn multiple concurrent threads with this code, they will each try to put a value into var1 and then when the PostProcessor will run, I will not have a guarantee that the var1 value which I am trying to use in the postprocessor, is actually the var1 value set by the current thread parent sampler. Could it be the value set by another thread?

Is this a valid concern, and if yes, how can I mitigate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are [**local to the thread**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage), each thread (virtual user) has its own instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class and other threads neither have read no write access to that `vars` object.

So your concert is not valid hence it doesn't require "mitigation" (whatever it means)

---

If you will need to pass data between threads/thread groups - it can be done via `props` object, this guy is "global" and accessible with any thread in any thread group (in fact in the whole [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) so `props` will still have values even if the test is ended but JMeter engine hasn't been yet shut down) so you need to be careful with it.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#properties) value can't be set by another thread

> JMeter variables are local to each thread